# Copying Postgresql DB dump from remote server to local

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, postgresql-13

I want to take a DB dump from a remote server and then copy this dump to my local.
I tried couple of commands but didn't worked.

Lastly I tried the command below;

```
pg_dump  -h 10.10.10.70 -p 5432  -U postgres -d mydb   | gzip > db1.gz
```

I succesffully take the DB and tried with restore from Pgadmin, it gives;

```
pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql
```

But at this point I can't use psql, I have to use Pgadmin and not sure if I'm able to get successfully DB dump to my local. I mean I can't verify with restore.

How can I take DB dump from remote server to my local?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "custom" format:

```sh
pg_dump -F c -h 10.10.10.70 -p 5432 -U postgres -f mydb.dmp mydb
```

That can be restores with `pg_restore` and hence with pgAdmin.

You do *not* have to use pgAdmin. pgAdmin uses `pg_restore`, and there is nothing that keeps you from using it too.

Comment: One last question, how can I automate the command with password? I tried "pg_dump -F c -h 10.10.10.70 -p 5432 -U postgres -W MYPASSWORD -f mydb.dmp mydb" but it gives "too many arguments" error.

Comment: Use a [password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html).